Deploying my Vaadin flow client build to my jelastic server
How would I deploy a frontend vaadin flow app? I’ve found the files after my build in the target/classes/META-INF/VAADIN/Webapp/ folder. In that folder I have index.html file and my build files, but when I upload this folder to my server I get a “Requested URL was not found”. My app runs perfect on my laptop and I placed it in production mode. I can’t seem to get it to work online. I know I’m missing something simple I just can’t figure it out. Any ideas?
I tried rebuilding the app and adding the offline-stub.html with no success.

What is jelastic server? Is this AWS Elastic? Or is it https://www.virtuozzo.com/application-platform/? As this company acquired Jelastic? I just want to clear this up, but weird that it is not working.
Are you using Vaadin Flow or the Hilla app? Usually, you need to do some cloud vendor-specific steps, deploys, and configuration before you can access your application from your cloud space/server.
Some more documentation about this is here:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/cloud-providers


I've fixed the problem. It was Spring boot. In Jelastic/vituozzo environment I was using apache and not spring server. When I created a spring server and generated a jar file using the instructions it worked great. I pray this helps someone else having this issue.

Could you create potentially an answer to your question with more details, it is not really clear what you did to me :) But it is good that you were able to solve, nice job!
